# Can't find one virtual machine whose network IPV4 is DHCP enabled

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip

I had a virtual machine which I connect remotely from my windows machine. Virtual machines TCP/IPV4 property was assigned one static IP address by the network administrator. I have changed that from static IP address to Automatic selection of IP address.Now I can't remote log in to that virtual machine either by machine name or IP address. Its showing error like machine can't be located. How can I locate my virtual machine and reset its TCP/IPV4 properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hypervisor, and whether or not you have the guest additions installed you may be able to view the configured IP address from the networking configuration area, or possibly the General information page of that VM's properties.

Alternatively, most hypervisors support launching a console from the management window. Right click on the VM and see what you have available for console options.

If those aren't available, visit your DHCP server and have a look at the leases. If it's a Windows DHCP server you'll be able to sort the leases by hostname and find the assigned IP that way.

If that's a nogo, try pinging the hostname. Maybe start with this. Depending on your environment DHCP may update DNS with its client details.

Yet another option would be scanning your network segment. Here's a BASH one liner that'll ping all the hosts in a range and then resolve live hosts against DNS.

```
for ip in 172.16.2.{1..254}; do ping -c 1 -w 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo $ip "$(nslookup $ip | grep 'name = ' | awk -F ' = ' '{print $2}')"; done
```

Comment: NP. Please mark as best answer if this helped. Thx.